# Is there a way to run multiple subscriber in parallel with Hot Publisher.- Reactive java

Tags: java, parallel-processing, reactive-programming, publish-subscribe

I am trying to run the multiple subscribers in parallel using ractive core library.

I tried using onSubscribe() and onPublish() methods but still it is getting executed sequentially.
As soon as flux was created it started new thread but runs all the subscriber and completes them in single thread.
I want multiple subscriber to run in parallel because i think data is already published to subscribers.

Code I am using is:

```
package com.citi.dglobe.builder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

public class Test {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FluxShareTestApplication3.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {      
        //Reader
        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("JAVA","SAMPLE");
         Flux<String> seq = Flux.fromIterable(list1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).publish().refCount(2); // refCount is the writerCount
                        
             
            //Writer. Could be more than 2
            List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2);
            list.stream().forEach((i) -> {
            
            //First Writer
            if(i==1) {
                    seq.subscribe(line -> {
                       try {
                       Thread.sleep(2000); // Thi ssleep is to check if the writer works in parallel
                      }
                      catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                      System.out.println("First Writer"+line);
                      logger.info("First Writer"+line);
                    });
             }
             //Second Writer
              else {
                 seq.subscribe(line -> {
                     try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000); // This sleep is to check if the writer works in parallel
                     }
                     catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                     System.out.println("Second Writer"+line);
                     logger.info("Second Writer"+line);
                    });
                 }
            }); // Closing list.stream.forEach
            Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    }
```

Need to know, How to run multiple subscriber in parallel for a hot publisher?.

The output I am getting is :

```
18:11:36.390 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
First WriterJAVA
18:11:38.560 [parallel-1] INFO com.citi.dglobe.builder.FluxShareTestApplication3 - First WriterJAVA
Second WriterJAVA
18:11:40.560 [parallel-1] INFO com.citi.dglobe.builder.FluxShareTestApplication3 - Second WriterJAVA
First WriterSAMPLE
18:11:42.561 [parallel-1] INFO com.citi.dglobe.builder.FluxShareTestApplication3 - First WriterSAMPLE
Second WriterSAMPLE
18:11:44.562 [parallel-1] INFO com.citi.dglobe.builder.FluxShareTestApplication3 - Second WriterSAMPLE
```

Comment: did you try to run your code? did it work of fail?

Comment: Updated the code. It is running now but in sequential. See the Output above

Comment: try https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#publishOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-